# What does Azure Active Directory Free Edition include?

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

Can I use free edition to create the following?

- add unlimited AD users
- employee access for custom apps
- allowing their pc to authenticate to azure ad
- connecting it with Visual Studio Team Services (previously Visual Studio Online) for ALM

One of our customer is proposing to use AD for authenticating end users [both employees, external users]. We are evaluating Azure AD - Free edition for the same.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/active-directory-editions/?

Comment: I searched elsewhere.. thanks for the link.. this has all details I was looking  for and clears most of the doubts :)